# How to derive a new colnum according to a given colnum in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have two columns like this:

| subject | regnum |
| --- | --- |
| 106001 | 2 |
| 106001 | 2 |
| 106001 | 2 |
| 106001 | 1 |
| 106001 | 1 |
| 106001 | 4 |
| 106001 | 4 |
| 106001 | 6 |
| 106001 | 6 |
| 106001 | 3 |
| 106001 | 3 |
| 106001 | 5 |
| 106001 | 5 |
| 106001 | 7 |
| 106001 | 7 |
| 106001 | 8 |

and I want a new column like this:

| subject | regnum | regnum_new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 106001 | 2 | 1 |
| 106001 | 2 | 1 |
| 106001 | 2 | 1 |
| 106001 | 1 | 2 |
| 106001 | 1 | 2 |
| 106001 | 4 | 3 |
| 106001 | 4 | 3 |
| 106001 | 6 | 4 |
| 106001 | 6 | 4 |
| 106001 | 3 | 5 |
| 106001 | 3 | 5 |
| 106001 | 5 | 6 |
| 106001 | 5 | 6 |
| 106001 | 7 | 7 |
| 106001 | 7 | 7 |
| 106001 | 8 | 8 |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data have;
input subject regnum;
datalines;
106001 2
106001 2
106001 2
106001 1
106001 1
106001 4
106001 4
106001 6
106001 6
106001 3
106001 3
106001 5
106001 5
106001 7
106001 7
106001 8
;

data want;
   set have;
   by subject regnum notsorted;
   if first.regnum then regnum_new + 1;
   if first.subject then regnum_new = 1;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your question to format the table. In your example, it seems there is only one Subject.

In that particular case, the following should do the trick:

```
data want;
    set have;
    by subject regnum notsorted;

    if first.regnum then
        regnum_new+1;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you. My bad. But actually I have a lot of subjects in my dataset.